# Display progress during execution of a Maximo Java Customization

Tags: java, maximo

I have written a Java customization for a client, attached to a button on one of their Maximo screens. It processes data from a group of tables, (I'm using direct JDBC for performance) does some calculations, and writes output to another table. It takes a while to run, (10 - 50 seconds), during which time the browser displays the busy cursor.

I'm new to the product. Does anyone know (I have read many many articles but no joy) how I might display some kind of progress to the user? I know I can throw an MXException to display a Dialog box, but that's no good. I'd love to display a progress bar, although I doubt that is possible.

But can anyone tell me whether I can obtain a reference to a field on the currently-displayed Maximo screen, and secondly, if I update it with a value (I'm thinking "% Complete") will it dynamically refresh on-screen, even though the browser is waiting on a response from the Maximo Server?

Answer (score 0):

See what you can find in the Migration Manager application. When you are building or deploying a package, it displays text messages / logs of what it has done so far. It's not as pretty as a progress bar, but it's way more interesting than the spinning wheel of busy-ness.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to route the logs to some manager object which emits appropriate progress update events to the OP's GUI as requested.